# yardstick::rmse on grouped data returns error and incorrect results

Tags: r, yardstick, tidymodels

I wanted to evaluate the performance of several regression model and used the `yardstick` package to calculate the RMSE. Here is some example data

```
  model obs pred
1     A   1    1
2     B   1    2
3     C   1    3
```

When I run the following code

```
library(yardstick)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
 group_by(model) %>%
 summarise(RMSE = yardstick::rmse(truth = obs, estimate = pred))
```

I get the following error

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :
>   no applicable method for 'rmse' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".

However, when I explicitly supply `.` as the first argument (which should not be necessary, I thought), I get no error, but the results are incorrect.

```
dat %>%
 group_by(model) %>%
 summarise(RMSE = yardstick::rmse(., truth = obs, estimate = pred))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  model   RMSE
  <fctr> <dbl>
1 A       1.29
2 B       1.29
3 C       1.29
```

I was expecting the following

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  model   RMSE
  <fctr> <dbl>
1 A       0
2 B       1.00
3 C       2.00
```

I know that there are alternatives to this function but still I don't  understand this behavior.

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(model = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), obs = c(1, 1, 1), pred = 1:3), .Names = c("model", "obs", "pred"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `do` function to apply the `rmse` function to every group.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(model) %>%
  do(data_frame(model = .$model[1], obs = .$obs[1], pred = .$pred[1], 
     RMSE = yardstick::rmse(., truth = obs, estimate = pred)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups: model [3]
# model    obs  pred  RMSE
#  <fctr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 A       1.00     1  0   
# 2 B       1.00     2  1.00
# 3 C       1.00     3  2.00
```

Or we can split the data frame and apply the `rmse` function.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(RMSE = dat %>%
           split(.$model) %>%
           sapply(yardstick::rmse, truth = obs, estimate = pred))
#   model obs pred RMSE
# 1     A   1    1    0
# 2     B   1    2    1
# 3     C   1    3    2
```

Or we can nest the `obs` and `pred` column to a list column and then apply the `rmse` function.

```
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  nest(obs, pred) %>%
  mutate(RMSE = sapply(data, yardstick::rmse, truth = obs, estimate = pred)) %>%
  unnest()
#   model RMSE obs pred
# 1     A    0   1    1
# 2     B    1   1    2
# 3     C    2   1    3
```

The output of these three methods are a little bit different, but all contain the right RMSE calculation. Here I use the `microbenchmark` package to conduct a performance evaluation.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(m1 = {dat %>%
    group_by(model) %>%
    do(data_frame(model = .$model[1], obs = .$obs[1], pred = .$pred[1], 
                  RMSE = yardstick::rmse(., truth = obs, estimate = pred)))},
    m2 = {dat %>%
        mutate(RMSE = dat %>%
                 split(.$model) %>%
                 sapply(yardstick::rmse, truth = obs, estimate = pred))},
    m3 = {dat %>%
        nest(obs, pred) %>%
        mutate(RMSE = sapply(data, yardstick::rmse, truth = obs, estimate = pred)) %>%
        unnest()})

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#   m1 43.18746 46.71055 50.23383 48.46554 51.05639 174.46371   100
#   m2 14.08516 14.78093 16.14605 15.74505 16.89936  24.02136   100
#   m3 28.99795 30.90407 32.71092 31.89954 33.94729  44.57953   100
```

The result shows that `m2` is the fastest, while `m1` is the slowest. I think the implication is `do` operation is usually slower then other methods, so if possible, we should avoid the `do` operation. Although `m2` is the fastest, personally I like the syntax of `m3` the best. The nested data frame will allow us to easily summarize information between different models or different groups.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer @www. The results are fine but it somehow feels wrong to use `do`, `sapply` etc. here instead of, say, `library(ModelMetrics);  dat %>% group_by(model) %>% summarise(RMSE = ModelMetrics::rmse(actual = obs, pred = pred))`.

Comment: Your question was about the rmse function from the yardstick package, and this function needs the first argument to be a data frame, while the rmse function from ModelMetrics package does not. You are free to select the function you like to do your task, but I believe since Phil and I both provide answers to your original question and they both work, you may consider accept one of the answers. Whether you think an answer make you feel right or wrong is irrelevant because that is subjective.

Comment: You put a desired output so Phil and I tried to use the function you specify to generate that output. I thought that was the question about. As for the explanation, when you do `yardstick::rmse(., truth = obs, estimate = pred)`. `.` represents the whole data frame, so `obs` and `pred` is the associated column from `.`, which shows the entire columns from the data frame. So the output is rmse of the entire data frame. All the methods Phil and I provided is somewhat "split" the data fame so `yardstick::rmse` can correctly identify which subset we are working on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought the question was about why I have to explicitly provide `.` as first argument although `%>%` would put it there anyway and why this function gives the same results for each group, after I called `group_by`. You're right of course that I can choose any other function but I thought it was worth a question.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my last comment. Had a typo in there and five minutes were over. Thanks for the last comment. This is what I was asking for, I guess. Sorry if that wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: No problem. I guess what you are looking for is a documentation showing how the pipe and dot from the `magrittr` package works.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the help page `?yardstick::rmse`, it looks like it expects a data frame as its first argument, which explains the error you're getting.

I'm not quite up to speed on that new package, but it seems that the function expects to calculate a summary statistic across a data frame, rather than a row-by-row calculation. To force it to run it row-by-row, you'd need to make it think that each row is its own dataframe, and apply the function within each of those data frames:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
  group_by(model) %>%
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(rmse_res = map(data, rmse, truth = obs, estimate = pred)) %>% 
  unnest(rmse_res)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  model  data              rmse
  <fctr> <list>           <dbl>
1 A      <tibble [1 x 2]>  0   
2 B      <tibble [1 x 2]>  1.00
3 C      <tibble [1 x 2]>  2.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Phil. From the documentation of the pipe operator: *The default behavior of `%>%` when multiple arguments are required in the rhs call, is to place lhs as the first argument, i.e. x %>% f(y) is equivalent to f(x, y).* That's why I was wondering that I have to explicitly supply `.` as first argument. Your solution works perfectly fine. However, I think it's quite complicated code for a rather simple calculation.

Comment: You have to supply the `.` because `yardstick::rmse()` expects a data frame as its first argument (i.e. the `x` in `f(x, y)`). You were getting the error you got because it was taking the `obs` variable as a data frame, and rejected for being a numeric variable. The function was then not doing what you expected because it was expecting the data frame to be the full data set to compare. I understand the frustration, but ultimately my response can only be to use the tool in the manner it's expected to be used. I'm not Max Kuhn (the author of the package).

Comment: As for the code being complicated, that is one of those YMMV things. I personally find it fairly elegant, and I'm partial to tidyverse code over base code (although as @www noted in his much more thorough answer than mine, it is less time-efficient). Given the tools to use and the data at hand, this is as simple as I can think to make it.

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Appreciate your answer and comments.